# GData ObjC - Duplicate Interface Definition Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to use GData ObjC library to upload videos from iPhone to Youtube.

When I try to build my project after adding the library (**present here :** svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata-objectivec-client-read-only) , I keep getting the error -**Duplicate interface definition for class 'GDataHTTPUploadFetcher'**- in GDataServiceBase.m.

However, when I do the same in a fresh project, I don't run into any issues at all. I have checked all the imports and project settings, they are all the same.

What should I look for, to resolve such an issue ?

---

### Additional Info :

(To answer one of Till's questions in the comments, because I'm not absolutely sure about categories)

In **GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.h**, this is how the interface is :

```
@interface GDataHTTPUploadFetcher : GDataHTTPFetcher {

GDataHTTPFetcher *chunkFetcher_;
BOOL needsManualProgress_
NSURL *locationURL_;
// uploadData_ or uploadFileHandle_ may be set, but not both
NSData *uploadData_;
NSFileHandle *uploadFileHandle_;
NSInteger uploadFileHandleLength_;
NSString *uploadMIMEType_;
NSUInteger chunkSize_;
BOOL isPaused_;

.
.
.

}

+ (GDataHTTPUploadFetcher *)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                      uploadData:(NSData *)data
                                  uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                                       chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize;

+ (GDataHTTPUploadFetcher *)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                uploadFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandle
                                  uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                                       chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize;

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       uploadData:(NSData *)data
 uploadFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandle
   uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
        chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize;

- (void)pauseFetching;
- (void)resumeFetchingWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
- (BOOL)isPaused;



@end
```

In **GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.m**, this is how the interface is :

```
@interface GDataHTTPUploadFetcher (InternalMethods)
- (void)uploadNextChunkWithOffset:(NSUInteger)offset;
- (void)uploadNextChunkWithOffset:(NSUInteger)offset
            fetcherProperties:(NSDictionary *)props;
- (void)destroyChunkFetcher;

- (void)uploadFetcher:(GDataHTTPFetcher *)fetcher
     didSendBytes:(NSInteger)bytesSent
   totalBytesSent:(NSInteger)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpected;

- (void)reportProgressManually;

- (NSUInteger)fullUploadLength;

// private methods of the superclass
- (void)invokeSentDataCallback:(SEL)sel
                    target:(id)target
           didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
         totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
 totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

- (void)invokeStatusCallback:(SEL)sel
                  target:(id)target
                  status:(NSInteger)status
                    data:(NSData *)data;

- (BOOL)invokeRetryCallback:(SEL)sel
                 target:(id)target
              willRetry:(BOOL)willRetry
                  error:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

In **GDataServiceBase.m**, this is how the interface is :

```
@interface GDataHTTPUploadFetcher : GDataHTTPFetcher
+ (GDataHTTPUploadFetcher *)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                      uploadData:(NSData *)data
                                  uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                                       chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize;
+ (GDataHTTPUploadFetcher *)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                uploadFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)uploadFileHandle
                                  uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                                       chunkSize:(NSUInteger)chunkSize;
- (void)pauseFetching;
- (void)resumeFetchingWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
- (BOOL)isPaused;
@end
```

But the problem is, this code only creates problems in one of the existing projects, and not in a fresh project.

Comment: What happens if you search for `@implementation GDataHTTPUploadFetcher` ? Do you see it in 2 files?

Comment: No it's present in one file only. But when I search for "@interface GDataHTTPUploadFetcher", it is found in 3 files : GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.h/.m and GDataServiceBase.m

Comment: I am assuming the interface definitions you find within implementation files (.m) are actually categories, correct?

Comment: I have updated my question, to answer your question. But like I said, the problem is this code only has issues in one of my existing projects, and not in a fresh project.

Comment: Please also include the relevant part of `GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.h`

Comment: I have updated the answer again to include the relevant part.

Comment: Well, there we got the issue... see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move all my code to a new project, and then everything worked.

So apparently, I had messed up something in my project settings.

Thanks so much for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Check your if your **Target** -> **Build Phases** -> **Compile Sources** possibly contains `GDataServiceBase.m` twice. If so remove one reference from that list.

[image]

Also thoroughly check all imports / includes and see if those possibly contain an implementation file (`.m`). A global search on `GDataServiceBase.m` will do the job.

Maybe you used an `#include` instead of an `#import` somewhere in your headers. Now if you do so, another `#include` of that same header within a header or implementation file including that header would cause a double-definition. `#import` works flawlessly even without guard-defines whereas `#include` needs those to prevent double-definitions.

After you posted the code, it became obvious. Those sources you are quoting are apparently double-defining the same class. I can only guess the reasoning; *straight forward bad design*.

---

**Finally, the cause**:

Apparently `GDataServiceBase.m` as well as `GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.h` define the very same class: `GDataHTTPUploadFetcher`. That certainly makes no sense. I can not answer on why the author did that, maybe it is just an outdated implementation file that is not supposed to be compiled anymore. Anyways, simply remove the entire `@interface` block from  `GDataServiceBase.m` up until and including the first `@end`.
The third interface definition (within `GDataHTTPUploadFetcher.m`) actually defines a category - that you can see because it includes brackets right behind the class/category name `(InternalMethods)`. And btw, the original author should not name them `InternalMethods` but simply open and close the bracket `()`. But everything here is his fault, not yours :D.

Comment: I see your point, but I checked the Compile Sources section, and it contains GDataService.m only once.

Comment: see my latest additions for another shot.

Comment: Tried that as well. Still no luck. Thanks so much for the addition though.

Comment: @ShahzebKhan new idea, thought it was worth a shot - see my latest edit

Comment: Checked that as well Till. Thanks once again for the addition.

Comment: When I comment out the interface in GDataServiceBase.m, it fixes the error, but gives a duplicate interface errror for some other class. When I comment out that interface, it fixes the error again, but gives 90 Mach-O-linker errors. This is so frustrating.

Comment: Ok, I think that settles it - the framework you are using is worth ZILCH, NIL, NULL, NARA :D